# Jquery get text of unorder list line items

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get the text value of a list item in an unordered list when the items is clicked on.

I've added an event listener and am logging the results to the console before I go any further.

When I selected by class I received only one line item, but it didn't matter which link you clicked it showed the same link text.  I've tried using `.eq()`, `this`, and a few other methods but either way I either return all 4 elements or no elements

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/troyb408/q8nzR/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mapSelections"> 
<ul>
    <li>Jump to State : </li>
    <li id="Conn" ><a href="#">Connecticut</a> |</li>
    <li id="Maine"><a href="#">Maine</a> |</li>
    <li id="Mass"><a href="#">Massachusetts</a> |</li>
    <li id="Rh"><a href="#">Rhode Island</a> |</li>
    <li id="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**And here is the listener:**

```
var link = document.getElementById('mapSelections');
link.addEventListener('click', function () {
   var text = $("li:eq()", this).text();
   console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener` if you're using jQuery, instead of using jQuery's event binding methods?

Comment: Teeeeeeeeeeechnically it is faster to use `addEventListener` than jQuery's `.on()` http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-vs-native/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

What you are trying to do is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You want to listen to the event from the parent `<div>` for events bubbling up from the child `<a>` tags.

You can delegate the event by using [jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
var link = document.getElementById('mapSelections');
$(link).on('click', 'a', function () {


    var text = $(this).text();
    //console.log(text);
    alert(text);
});
```

[Here is updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8nzR/9/)

### Explanation

Basically there are two options for what you want:

#### Multiple Listeners

```
$("#mapSelections a").on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

This works fine but you are binding event listeners to several elements (one listener to each `<a>` tag). There is a bit of overhead for each one so it's not the most performant option available to you.

#### Event Delegation

```
$("#mapSelections").on('click', 'a', function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

The reason (IMO) this is best is because you are saving your application some resources. You are binding only one listener to the parent `$("#mapSelections")`, and that element is then waiting for events that bubble up **only from child `<a>` tags**.

Comment: But document.getElementById('mapSelections') does not select links so I wouldn't do it like this.

Comment: Thats not what I said, did you read my comment? Compair your answer with mine and you will see the difference.

Comment: I know the difference, it's the same as everybody else's. Yours adds a listener to each child (like 6 event listeners) while mine has only one. The second parameter in `.on()` lets you choose what elements the event needs to bubble from

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this works well with the second half of what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q8nzR/1/

I just edited a few lines of your jQuery:

```
$('#mapSelections a').on('click', function () {


    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
    //alert(text);
});
```

Your problem was, that THIS was not reffering to a single a, but the whole div#mapSelections instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should bind the handler to the `LI`, not the whole `DIV`.

```
$("#mapSelections li").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("a").text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. You are binding several listeners (one for each `li`) AND parsing the result looking for `<a>`. That is unnecessary for what OP is trying to do and doesn't exemplify good JS practice..

Comment: I think it's pretty idiomatic jQuery use. And unless it's a solution that doesn't work, I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: No, idiomatic jQuery would be something more like `$("#mapSelections a")` or the answer I provided. This is just unnecessarily bulky

Comment: The question says you can click on the LI, not just the A. Your answer is unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: Actually the question makes no mention of clicking the `<li>` anywhere.

Comment: The first line says _text value of a list item in an unordered list when the items is clicked on._ `<li>` is HTML for `list item`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52225/discussion-between-martin-and-barmar)